# wavelength and L/C ratio

Tags: rf, radio

When choosing the L/C ratio in this reference text states that you need to
choose 1.5pf for one meter wavelength. Why is that?
How that leads to have higher gain? How that leads to have a 
higher dynamic resistance?

> [Basic radio theory, circuits and calculations](http://www.ukradioamateur.co.uk/full/html/c2-1-13.htm)

What is the connection between these two?

--thanks in advance--

Comment: The reference you have linked does *not* say that you **need** to choose 1.5 pF per meter wavelength. It says: *it is **convenient to assume** that the value of C is 1.5pF per metre of wavelength*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the link says, it's a design optimisation. They want to maximise the Q-factor (energy retention versus power loss) of the circuit, but as your wavelength increases (and antenna), the amount of stray capacitance increases. They use 1.5pC*L as an engineering rule of thumb to get you the amount impedance you need.

Read more on Q-factor here to understand it in the frequency spectrum: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_factor